# AFNetworking, using shared AFHttpSessionManager, pending request is cancelled when a newer request complete

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFHTTPSessionManager in singleton mode, and start multiple request like :

```
[MyAPI testSlow]; 
[MyAPI testQuick];
```

MyAPI definition:

```
+(void)testSlow { 
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [BPNetworkManager sharedManager]; // Get Manager Singleton 
NSString *urlString = [BPCommonUtils getUrlByPath:@"/api/test/testSlow"];
[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success: ^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject) { 
   NSLog(@"slowSuccess"); 
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error){ 
   NSLog(@"slowFail"); 
}];
```

}

```
+(void)testQuick { 
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [BPNetworkManager sharedManager]; 
NSString *urlString = [BPCommonUtils getUrlByPath:@"/api/test/testQuick"]; 
[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success: ^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject) { 
NSLog(@"quickSuccess"); 
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error){ 
NSLog(@"quickFail"); 
}]; 
}
```

When 'quick Task' returned with success, the 'slow Task' failed immediately, fail message info : 
@"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550617

@"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"cancelled"

How can I solve it? Thank you!